# Generating huge lists of numbers

Tags: bash, scripting, operations, largenumber

I'm trying to generate a huge list of sequenced numbers with 0 padding

```
 for example:
 00000000
 00000001
 00000002
 .
 .
 99999997
 99999998
 99999999
```

im trying something like:

```
 for i in $(seq 00000000 99999999);do echo ${i} >> filelist.txt;done
```

this has two problems.

```
 1: the range is too big and the system cant handle it
 2: the numbers arent padded so I end up with something like this:

 1
 2
 3
 .
 .
 998
 999
 1000
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`seq` already knows how to do padding.

```
seq -w 00000000 00000009 >filelist.txt
```

There's also `-f` for more general formats (mostly useful when the increment isn't an integer). For more complex output, the best solution would be to postprocess the output of `seq` with `sed` or other text processing tools.

Comment: your solution was a lot better than mine, serves me right for not reading the man page :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this in 2 steps

```
seq 10 > file

while read i; do printf "%.8d\n" $i; done < file
00000001
00000002
00000003
00000004
00000005
00000006
00000007
00000008
00000009
00000010
```